# What does the error "binary.Write: invalid type" mean?

Tags: go

The code shown below, I create a struct type and want to encode it to binary.
But it show `binary.Write: invalid type main.Stu` error, I had read some similar code like this,but I can't find why my code doesn't work?

```golang
type Stu struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Id int
}

func main()  {
    s := &Stu{
        Name: "Leo",
        Age: 21,
        Id: 1,
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, s)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", buf)
}
```

Comment: You did not read the documentation of encoding/binary.Write: "Data must be a
    fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such data."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) cannot be used to encode arbitrary values that have non-fixed size. `int` and `string` are such examples. Quoting from [`binary.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write):

> Write writes the binary representation of data into w. **Data must be a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such data.**

Note that if you remove the `string` field and change `int` fields to `int32`, it'll work:

```
type Stu struct {
    Age int32
    Id  int32
}

func main() {
    s := &Stu{
        Age: 21,
        Id:  1,
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", buf)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kesQeikHFCH)):

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x01"
```

As the doc suggests, to encode complex structures, use [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/).

Example of encoding and decoding using `encoding/gob`:

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
if err := enc.Encode(s); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%v\n", buf.Bytes())

dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
var s2 *Stu
if err := dec.Decode(&s2); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s2)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h4T2YGBK0eK)):

```
[41 255 129 3 1 1 3 83 116 117 1 255 130 0 1 3 1 4 78 97 109 101 1 12 0 1 3 65 103 101 1 4 0 1 2 73 100 1 4 0 0 0 12 255 130 1 3 76 101 111 1 42 1 2 0]
&{Name:Leo Age:21 Id:1}
```

Comment: binary.Write can write structs. It can't write `string` or `int` because they're not fixed-size.

Comment: @icza Thanks, I'll remeber it in my heart.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't the same output. I'm currently encountering the problem. I have a frame to send, in a struct that have 7 variables in it: mostly uint16 and []byte. The binary content it has to send is: `{0x4E, 0x55, 0x06, 0x1F, 0x40, 0x74, 0x04, 0xCF, 0x90, 0x65, 0x2C, 0xBF, 0x19}` but what it sends on the network with `gob` is this melt with: Data, Synchronization, FrameNumber: the variables names inside my struct.
The receiver doesn't 13 bytes of binary content, but something about 50 bytes in a Go serialized format, incompatible with anything else.