# Integer to Byte conversion in Java vs Go

Tags: java, go, integer, byte

I want to connect two server apps. One is written in Java and the other one in Go. Both communicate via a simple protocol on byte level.

At the Go app I got this result:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 17)
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, 1066249)
```

0 = {uint8} 79
1 = {uint8} 74
2 = {uint8} 16
3 = {uint8} 0

---

But if I do the same in my Java app, I got this numbers:

```
byte[] result = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(1066249).array();
```

0 = 9
1 = 69
2 = 16
3 = 0

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong on the Java side?

Comment: The Java result is correct. 1066249 is 0x00104509, in little-endian that's 0x09 0x45 0x10 0x00, or 9 69 16 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I try to execute the [code](https://play.golang.org/p/d82vaIqgkfd) you have shared, it gives a proper error message

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Error writing to the buffer, binary.Write: invalid type int
```

And here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842245/what-does-the-error-binary-write-invalid-type-mean) why you can not use arbitrary size values

The recommended approach is to handle the error, the error code gives the reason for the failure or the unexpected behavior. Here is the working code that gives same result as java

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

    func main() {
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        var data int32 = 1066249
        err := binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error writing to the buffer, %s", err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v", buf.Bytes())
    }
```

output

```
[9 69 16 0]
```

Here is the PlayGround [link](https://play.golang.org/p/qDnS2yESD9T) to the working code